# Azure media player source manifist

Tags: azure-media-services, shaka, azure-media-player

We are very small junior school private tutors have setup of an online portal where students can login and watch the daily video lectures.  We have many videos uploaded to Azure media services but we realized the encoding cost is high and not affordable. So I encoded a video using FFMPEG and generated m4s and audio file and .mpd (metadata) using MPBox in my local.
I have copied all the files on Azure blob storage and blob storage have HTTPS access. Can I use .mpd as source url for Azure media player ?
e.g. Azure media player source is //amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/3b970ae0-39d5-44bd-b3a3-3136143d6435/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest

but my generated metadata from MPDBox is
https://bb.sourceoftraining.companywebinternet.storage/ssj-ewrrer-2343s-ssssdf23/process_and_benifits.mpd

Or any other player I can use. I tried Shaka player but unable to show the Resolution and Playback speed settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading pre-encoded MP4's works just fine. I suggest you download the latest version of the Azure Media Explorer tool for the v3 API.  In there you can now upload an MP4 into a new asset, and have it generate the client and server manifests needed for streaming.  Just upload to a new empty Asset, and then double click on the asset to get to the tab for the files, and click the generate manifests buttons.
That pre-gens the required manifest files needed for streaming an MP4 that is pre-encoded with closed 2 second GOPs.  The tool pre-generates both the client and server manifest and saves them back into the asset to improve the playback performance from the streaming server.

You can use Azure Media Player to play back DASH, Smooth, or HLS - but the technology that it chooses to use for playback differs by platform.  For example depending on the browser version, OS, or mobile client it will chose to load a different player tech or it will use the built-in OS player support.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/azure-media-player/azure-media-player-overview

For DASH content (.mpd) the AMP player chooses to use Dash on Windows, and on Android in specific conditions.  It does this by detecting the platform and using the right tech combined with the /manifest(format=mpd-time-cmaf) format on the URL.  You can learn more about how "dynamic packaging" works in AMS here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/dynamic-packaging-overview

There are various "format" options on the streaming locator URL in AMS that provide different manifest formats back.

Smooth Streaming = /manifest
MPEG-DASH-CMAF = /manifest(format=mpd-time-cmaf)
HLS with CMAF  = manifest(format=m3u8-cmaf)
HLS v3 (TS) =  /manifest(format=m3u8-aapl-v3)

Using one of those various formats, you can use any 3rd party player that supports them. Shaka, HLS.js, Exoplayer on Android, iOS AvFoundation native player, Video.js, or even the 'adpater-player' noted by Jason above. Any player that supports the current HLS or DASH specifications should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have School email addresses that you can use for yourself and your students the simplest solution would be to leverage capabilities from Microsoft Stream via the free O365 education plan - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/academic/compare-office-365-education-plans. Info on Microsoft Stream at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/microsoft-stream.

And to clarify feedback Jason Pan just provided, while Azure Media Player doesn't support just pointing at .mpd file for playback this is rather done via first creating appropriate server manifest and then requesting .mpd manifest via format option in the URL clients will use to request content. Media Services will then dynamically create the appropriate manifest to respond to the client request. See John's response for links to articles with additional feedback on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Shaka Player's UI library, you'll be able to display the Resolution and Playback speed settings.

[Shaka UI library](https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-ui.html)  [Shaka Player Demo](https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/demo/)